# Checking to see if Formal Parameter is Null in Java

Tags: java, string, null

I've pretty much completed everything I needed to for what I am doing. The only thing that is left is "Checking to see if the formal parameter is null".

Which has to do with this code.

```
    public boolean setLabel(String labelIn) {
       labelIn = labelIn.trim();
       if (labelIn == null) {
          boolean isSet = false;
       }
       label = labelIn;
       boolean isSet = true;
       return isSet;
    }
```

Sorry if the post is off, or unclear. First time posting.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You are supposed to check if it's null **before** using it (running `trim()` if `labelIn` happens to be `null` will result in a `NullPointerException`.)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about the question. I was asking exactly how to check the formal parameter is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have your code written is *almost* right. You want to check if the value is null before you call a method, otherwise it'll throw an error. Also, you can do away with your boolean for returning the value and just use in-place return statements; it's a bit more efficient.

```
public boolean setLabel(String labelIn) {
   if (labelIn == null) {
      return false;
   }
   labelIn = labelIn.trim();
   label = labelIn;
   return true;
}
```

### OR

Throw the error! If it's the caller's fault for passing in a `null` parameter, he should have to deal with the consequences (at that point, you may want to consider changing its return type):

```
public void setLabel(String labelIn) {
   labelIn = labelIn.trim();
   label = labelIn;
}
```

Comment: One could also avoid the explicit `null` check and instead catch the `NullPointerException` that `labelIn.trim()` with throw if `labelIn` is `null`.  I'm not sure whether that would satisfy the requirements, though.

Comment: Throwing is also computationally expensive, but I'll update my answer to include that philosophy @JohnBollinger

Comment: This ended up being right. Apparently it was the order in which things were in. Thanks Michael! Also the simple return true and false statements are much better.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: It's typically considered bad practice to use exceptions as part of the normal, expected control flow. It's obvious that this method is designed to fail gracefully when given an invalid label, so catching a null reference exception that you could have just as easily avoided throwing in the first place is just messy.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, if a null argument is invalid (unclear from the question), then the case where the argument is `null` is not part of the normal, expected control flow.  Avoiding pre-testing for normal, expected conditions is one of the core use cases for exception handling.  It is also slightly cheaper to avoid the null test when the argument indeed is not null, and it can be clearer.

Comment: @Michael, I wasn't suggesting that the method allow the NPE to escape.  I was suggesting catching it inside the method.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I understood what you were suggesting, but if you look at the method signature and implementation, it's very clear that it's designed to permit the method to be called with an invalid value, in which case it's expected to return false. Since the method signature is set up specifically to handle that case, I would assume that the designers expect this to be a fairly common occurrence, not an exceptional one.